# Application of Bolzano's theorem to polynomials

Tags: polynomials, continuity

I am trying to solve the following:

> Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n$, say $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^nc_kx^k$, such that the first and last coefficients $c_0$ and $c_n$ have opposite signs. Prove that $f(x)=0$ for at least one positive $x$.

I can use [Bolzano's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BolzanosTheorem.html) for $x=0$ and some other value of $x$, but I am not sure which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint: For $x>0$ you can write
$$f(x)=x^n \left(c_n+{c_{n-1}\over x}+{c_{n-2}\over x^2}+\ldots+{c_0\over x^n}\right)\ .$$
What about the sign of $f(M)$ when $M\gg1\ $?

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(c_n)\infty=-\operatorname{sgn}(f(0))\infty
$$
where 
$
\operatorname{sgn}(c)$ is the sign of $c$, i.e. $\operatorname{sgn}(c)=\dfrac{|c|}{c}$, for $c\neq0.
$

This mean that we can find a "large" $x$ such that the sign of $f(x)$ is the opposite of the sign of $f(0)$. I leave the details to you.